# Chinese New Year Equation 2016

Tags: diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics, sums-of-squares

In the spirit of Chinese New Year, here's a problem to commemorate the year.

> $\color{black}{\text{Solve the following equation for positive integers $a$ and $b$:}}$
>   $$\color{red}{a^2+b^2+(a+8)^2+(b+8)^2=100a+b}$$

---

*Edit 1*

As this question has been put on hold and the OP asked to improve the question by providing additional context", please find below some additional details.

Having read about [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) and after some work, I noticed an interesting four-square combination for the year. Hence I thought I would formulate it as a problem - which turns out to be a diophantine equation - to see what different approaches there might be. A straightforward approach would be to rearrange the terms into a the standard circle formula
$(a-21)^2+\left(b+\frac {15}4\right)^2=\left(\frac{\sqrt{6257}}4\right)^2\approx19.77^2$ and then testing integer values of $a$ within $21\pm 19.77$, but there should be other more interesting approaches.

Hopefully the explanation above will be sufficient for the question to be reopened. Moderators - please advise if there is additional context required. 
Thanks.

---

*Edit 2*

Thanks for the nice answers by Hagen and Daniel. The interesting point to note here is that:

> $$\color{red}{20}^2+\color{red}{16}^2+(\color{red}{20}+8)^2+(\color{red}{16}+8)^2=\color{red}{2016}$$

$\color{black}{\text{To all readers who celebrate, a very Happy Chinese New Year!!}}$

---

*Note: This question has been put on hold.  If you find it interesting or useful,* **please vote to reopen it** *(by clicking on "reopen" at the bottom of this post), so that others can post their solutions. Thanks!*

Comment: Well, actually it was almost a week ago. But still cheers!

Comment: Just a sidenote: [there are about 5% of the population which suffer from one or another form of color-blindness](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195/on-the-use-of-color-in-equations)…

Comment: @Vim: yes, but still within the 15 days! cheers to you too!

Comment: @Watson: The colour was for festive purposes as this is a recreational-mathematics post. Anyway now edited so that only the equation is in festive red. Hopefully not too much inconvenience caused.

Comment: @hypergeometric : no problem! It is better now, I think. Funny question!

Comment: I agree this should be reopened.

Comment: Elementary , my dear @Watson! :)

Comment: But the Chinese Year changed from 4713 to 4714...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First write it as $$(a-21)^2 +(b+\frac{15}{4})^2= \frac{6257}{16} = 1+\frac{79^2}{4^2}$$

$$\Rightarrow (a-21)^2-1 = \frac{79^2}{4^2}-(b+\frac{15}{4})^2$$

Now use difference of squares to get

$$(a-22)(a-20) = \bigg( \frac{4b+94}{4}\bigg)\bigg( \frac{64-4b}{4}\bigg)$$

We see we get corresponding positive integer solutions in $b$ for $a = 22$ and $a = 20$(since we only need one of the factors on the **RHS** to be $0$), namely $b = 16$.

Else we need **RHS** to be an integer (since the **LHS** clearly is), which will happen only when$$(4b+94)(64-4b) \equiv 0 \pmod{16} $$ $$\Rightarrow b = 18n$$

However it is easy to check that we get no new solutions from this. To see this write it as $$(a-21)^2 = \frac{6257}{16}-(18n+\frac{15}{4})^2$$

$$\color{red}{\text{Happy 2016!}}$$

Comment: This is brilliant! Can you please elaborate on the "After some work" part? How did you arrive at the magical and neatly factorised form?

Comment: See the edited answer @hypergeometric. And happy New Year to you! :)

Comment: How do you get from $(4b+94)(64-4b)\equiv 0\pmod{16}$ to $b=18n$? After all, already $b\equiv 0\pmod 2$ implies $(4b+94)(64-4b)\equiv 0\pmod{16}$ ...

Comment: Thanks for your additional explanation and your solution! Very neat factorisation! (+1) Happy  2016 to you too!

Answer (score 3):

The difference of the two sides (which must be $0$) equals
$$\tag12(a-21)^2 +2(b-11)^2+59b-996\ge 59b-996$$
so that $b\le 16$. Also, the left hand side of $(1)$ is $\equiv b\pmod 2$, hence $b$ is even, $b=2c$ with $1\le c\le 8$. Substituting and dividing by $2$ we arrive at
$$ 0=(a-21)^2+\underbrace{4c^2+15c-377}_{-358\,\ldots\,-1}$$
and check for which $c\in\{1,\ldots,8\}$ the number $377-4c^2-15c$ happens to be a perfect square. The only case is $c=8$ (so $b=16$) and leads to $a-21=\pm1$, i.e., $a=20$ or $a=22$.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. By completing the square you get $2(a-21)^2$ but how did you arrive at $2(b-11)^2$ instead of $2(b+\frac{15}4)^2$?

Comment: Typo $15$ for $16$.

Comment: @hypergeometric Among all choices of "$b$ minus integer", this gave the best bound (i.e., $Ab-B$ with $B/A$ minimal).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and your solution! (+1)